# Bootstrap 4 table tbody spinner wrong position on chrome and Internet explorer

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a dynamically spinner in a table tbody bootstrap 4.
I have tried this way:

HTML

```
<div class="container mt-2">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
          <span class="table-title">table</span>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
          <table id="contact-list" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm bstable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Click</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>b</td>
              <td>c</td>  
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bstable tbody {
  position: relative;
}
.bstable tbody .overlay-spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

JS

```
var s = '<div class="spinner-grow text-primary spinner-grow-sm mt-2"><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div>;
$( '.bstable' ).find( 'tbody' ).append( '<div class="overlay-spinner text-center">' + s + '</div>' );
```

With firefox the spinner is correctly shown in tbody, while with the other browsers (chrome, edge, explorer) the spinner is shown above the table.
[See my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arwpz71y/)

Unfortunately I can not understand where the problem is. 
Can you help me to solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

please add the spinner to the div around your table and not to the table body in JS. Then adjust it with top 50% and left 50% and reduce this alignment by the height and width of the spinner to adjust it right in the middle. after that i removed the bottom margin from the tables parent div to get the spinner exactly in the middle of the table.

```js
var s = '<div class="spinner-grow text-primary spinner-grow-sm mt-2"><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div>';

$('.table-responsive').append('<div class="overlay-spinner text-center">' + s + '</div>');
```

```css
table.table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.table-responsive {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.overlay-spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /*dim the background*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container mt-2">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div>
            <span class="table-title">TABLE</span>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
            <table id="contact-list" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm bstable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Click</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Kudos! I was writing this solution and then your answer popped up. :)

Comment: thank you, but the spinner should be shown above the tbody at the top as shown by firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Find below solution.

I've done it with 'tr' tag for wrapper element of the loader.

Loader stays vertically in center dispute of rows added.
But you need to explicitly set colspan when ever new column is added or removed, to keep the loader horizontally center.

Replace 'loading' text with your loader animation.

```css
table {
  position: relative;
}

tbody {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.loading {
  position: absolute;
  background: antiquewhite;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Click</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="loading">
      <td colspan="3">
        loading
      </td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working well in my scenario. https://jsfiddle.net/dq3o2vky/